# Ask question interstitial on Meta Stack Exchange links to incorrect website

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, new-users

If you go to the ask question interstitial page shown to new users on this site:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice?

And click on the hyperlink that the arrow points to, it will go to
`https://stack-overflow.com/questions/ask` which does not load for me. Shouldn't it link to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask` instead?

[image]

Comment: Yes. This looks like a typo in the hyperlink.

Comment: Perhaps that's why we get many programming questions here?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog "Perhaps that's why we get SO many programming questions here?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the heads-up! I've removed the errant hyphen.

Lesson learned: ask for a proof-read when editing copy on your phone from a dentist's chair.

Comment: Lesson learned: do not make changes to the system from your phone when sitting on a dentist's chair.

Comment: Question. Is this on or off the happy gas?